What's the derivative of $\int_{0}^{x^2}\sqrt{t^4+x^3}\, dt$?
Given
$$
F(x) = \int_{0}^{x^2}\sqrt{t^4+x^3}\, dt
$$
what's $F'(x)$?
I know if $g(x,y)$ is a continuous function and
$$
G(x) = \int_a^bg(x,y)\, dy
$$
then $G'(x) =\displaystyle \int_a^bg_x(x,y)\,dy$.
If the limit of the integral is also a function of $x$, chain rule can be applied. For the above function $F$, I write it as a function of 2 variables
$$
H(x,y) = \int_0^y\sqrt{t^4+x^3}\, dt,
$$
where $y$ is a function of $x$ ($y=x^2$ here). Thus, what I know is, $F'(x)$ can be expressed as
$$
F'(x) = H_1+H_2\cdot dy/dx,
$$
where $H_i$ is the partial derivative of $H$ regarding the $i$-th component. $H_2$ is easy to find. However, I get stuck into calculating $H_1$:
$$
H_1 = \frac{3x^2}{2}\cdot \int_0^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^4+x^3}}\,dt.
$$
All above is what I tried. Is there other ways to find $F'(x)$? Or did I do something wrong?

What you've done looks right to me so far. Just remember to replace the upper limit of integration to $y = x^2$. I'm not sure if you can find an elementary antiderivative for this. It will probably involve elliptic integrals.

The answer to such problems is given by the following rule:
Newton Leibniz Rule:

So in this case,
$$u(x)=x^2$$
$$v(x)=0 (\text{constant})$$
$$H(t)=\sqrt{t^4+x^3}$$
Hence the Answer is:
Final Answer:

You can treat the $x$-term inside of the integrand as constant since the function integrates it wrt to $t$, therefore the $x$-function of the limit and the $x$-term of the integrand only interact once we apply the rule.
(I'm new here so kindly excuse the lack of latex)

You should try learning to type yourself, see here :https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1196653
